Prove inequality $ \frac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^n}\ < \frac{1}{n}\ $ for any x
I'm trying to prove next inequality: $ \frac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^n}\ < \frac{1}{n}\ $
for $|x| < 1$ and any $n \in\ N$
I've tried to use induction (can't make induction step) and taylors formula (I got result depends on x).

Did you try using Bernoulli's inequality?

Did you try to rewrite it as $nx^2 < (1+x^2)^n$? Can you expand RHS?

No context and little effort shown here. You've been here long enough to know this goes against the MSE Guidelines. -1 and Vote-To-Close

The proposed inequality is a direct consequence of the Bernoulli's inequality:
\begin{align*}
(1 + x^{2})^{n} \geq 1 + nx^{2} > nx^{2}
\end{align*}

This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
